# i cant see action bar on nexus 5

Tags: android, android-actionbar

this my problem: 
when i execute the app on emulator this shows the actionbar, but when i install apk on nexus 5, not shows it

a detail of manifest and styles next:

```
<uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="11"
       android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>
```

any idea?

thanks, and sorry about my english

Comment: Can you post some screenshots, and the code of your main activity that doesn't have the action bar?

Comment: thanks hichris123, It´s solved!, i forgot change a "style" tag.

Comment: You can then post your solution as an answer, and mark it as accepted.